# lines.sma30 and lines.sma50 cause problem

Tags: python, yfinance, backtrader

```py
import backtrader as bt
import yfinance as yf

# Download data from yfinance
data = yf.download("AAPL", period="max")
# Convert the data to a Pandas DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Convert the DataFrame to a PandasData object
data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=data)

# Instantiate Cerebro with the downloaded data
cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.adddata(data)

# Add the SMA indicators to Cerebro
cerebro.addindicator(bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage, period=30, plotname="sma30")


cerebro.addindicator(bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage, period=50, plotname="sma50")


# Create the strategy
class MyStrategy(bt.Strategy):
    def start(self):
        # Access the indicator values using the `lines` attribute

        if self.lines["sma30"][0] > self.lines["sma50"][0]:

            # Buy if not already in a position

            if not self.position:
                self.buy()
        else:
            # Sell if in a position
            if self.position:
                self.sell()


# Add the strategy to Cerebro
cerebro.addstrategy(MyStrategy)

# Run the backtest
cerebro.run()
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I tried dropping the plot labels from the indicators but the lines.sma30 and lines.sma50 are always trouble. I fear ***backtrader*** doesn't have a good tutorial online as ***YahooFinanceCSVData*** doesn't work actually, so I used ***yfinance***.

Answer (score 0):

1. The method `YahooFinanceCSVData` for download data from Yahoo Finance! is depreciated. You can download the data and save it to a csv file and use the method to load the data to cerebro.
2. The indicator should be declared within the strategy. Basically your `strategy()` method is the main logic that contain everything related to your trade.
   Example:

```py
class MyStrategy(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataclose = self.datas[0].close
        # Define indicators in the __init__ funcition
        self.sma30 = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(period = 30)
        self.sma50 = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(period = 50)

    def next(self):
        # Return the current value and decide what you want to do in the next bar
        if self.sma30[0] > self.sma50[0]:

            # Buy if not already in a position
            if not self.position:
                self.buy()
        else:
            # Sell if in a position
            if self.position:
            # After buy, you should use `close()` to close your position
                self.close()
```

This will help you to access the indicator data.

Here is my example strategy in full form:

```py
class SimpleRSI(bt.Strategy):
    params = (
        ('printlog', True),
        ('period', 14),
        ('upperband', 60.0),
        ('lowerband', 40.0),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.dataclose = self.datas[0].close
        # To keep track of pending orders and buy price/commission
        self.order = None
        self.buyprice = None
        self.buycomm = None
        # Add a RSI indicator
        self.rsi = btind.RelativeStrengthIndex(period=self.params.period, upperband=self.params.upperband, lowerband=self.params.lowerband)

    def log(self, txt, dt=None, doprint=False):
        if self.params.printlog or doprint:
            dt = dt or self.datas[0].datetime.date(0)
            print('%s, %s' % (dt.isoformat(), txt))

    def notify_order(self, order):
        if order.status in [order.Submitted, order.Accepted]:
            # Buy/Sell order submitted/accepted to/by broker - Nothing to do
            return

        # Check if an order has been completed
        # Attention: broker could reject order if not enough cash
        if order.status in [order.Completed]:
            if order.isbuy():
                self.log(
                    'BUY EXECUTED, Price: %.2f, Cost: %.2f, Comm %.2f' %
                    (order.executed.price,
                     order.executed.value,
                     order.executed.comm))

                self.buyprice = order.executed.price
                self.buycomm = order.executed.comm
            else:  # Sell
                self.log('SELL EXECUTED, Price: %.2f, Cost: %.2f, Comm %.2f' %
                         (order.executed.price,
                          order.executed.value,
                          order.executed.comm))

            self.bar_executed = len(self)

        elif order.status in [order.Canceled, order.Margin, order.Rejected]:
            self.log('Order Canceled/Margin/Rejected')

        self.order = None

    def next(self):
        # Simply log the closing price of the series from the reference
        self.log('Close, %.2f' % self.dataclose[0])

        # Check for open orders
        if self.order:
            return

        # Check if we are not in the market
        if not self.position:
            # Not yet ... we MIGHT BUY if ...
            if self.rsi[0] > 60:
                # BUY, BUY, BUY!!! (with all possible default parameters)
                self.log('BUY CREATE, %.2f' % self.dataclose[0])
                # Keep track of the created order to avoid a 2nd order
                size = self.broker.getvalue() / self.dataclose[0]
                self.order = self.buy(size = size)
                self.stoploss = self.dataclose[0]*0.99
                self.takeprofit = self.dataclose[0]*1.03
        else:
            if self.dataclose[0] < self.stoploss:
                self.log('STOP LOSS, %.2f' % self.dataclose[0])
                self.order = self.sell(size=self.position.size)
            elif self.dataclose[0] > self.takeprofit:
                self.log('TAKE PROFIT, %.2f' % self.dataclose[0])
                self.order = self.sell(size=self.position.size)
```

Feel free to use this as a blueprint to write your strategies.